# python requests library , save session to file

Tags: python, python-requests, pickle

I am trying to find a way for saving a session object `requests.session()` to a file and then continue my session from another python script from the same place, include the cookies, the headers etc.

I've try doing that with `pickle` but for some reason the session's cookies and all other attributes are not loaded from file.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want look into serialization, something like `pickle`
For example you would open a file  and dump the session with `pickle.dump(sess, f)` and read with `pickle.load(f)` into a session object